# How to position the nav elements to the top right

Tags: html, css

```
<header class="top-header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="./dist/img/usjr-logo.png" alt="" href="http://www.usjr.edu.ph" id="logo">
        </div>

        <nav class ="top-nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Link A1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link A2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Link A3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </div>
</header>

<nav class="navigation-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link B1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link B4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

That is the block code of my index.html file

And here is my css file :

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Open+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');
/*@import "heading.css" ; */
/*Main Elements*/
* { -
    margin : 0 ; border: 0; padding: 0; 
}

body { 
    background-color :#ececec; 
    font: 14px/20px'Nunito','sans-serif'; 
    color : #444; margin : 0 ; 
}

.wrapper { 
    margin : 0 auto; 
    width :70%; 
    clear : both; 
}

.container {
    margin-left : 30px;
    margin-right : 30px;
}

img#logo{
    height : 80px;
    width : auto;
    margin : 10px;
}

ul { 
    list-style : none ;
}

nav.top-nav > ul > li {
    display : inline-block; 
}

nav.top-nav > ul > li > a{
    color :#fff;
    text-decoration: none ;
    padding : 30px ; 
    text-align : right ;
}


header.top-header { 
    margin-top : 10px;
    background-color : #FFF;
    height :100px;
}


nav.navigation-menu { 
    background-color : #444;
    color : #fff;
    height : 50px;
}

nav.navigation-menu > ul > li > a {
    color : #FAB301  ;
}
```

here is an image [image]

What i want is to put to the top the Link A's on the top right-center of the navigation of the top-header class. How can I do it  ?

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/3aho893g/3/)

If you want the menu options all the way to the right side and at the top of the screen, change the following:

```
nav.top-nav {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
nav.top-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: I want it to move on the top-header and position it on top-nav which has the background of white not to stay on the main-navigation menu right part

Comment: ah ok... I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.top-nav {
  float: right;
}
```

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it. Then the element is taken from the normal flow of the web page, though still remaining a part of the flow, contrary to absolute positioning.
>
> REF:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float?v=example

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Open+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');

/*@import "heading.css" ; */


/*Main Elements*/

* {
  - margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ececec;
  font: 14px/20px'Nunito', 'sans-serif';
  color: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

img#logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav.top-nav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.top-nav {
  float: right;
}

nav.top-nav>ul>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

header.top-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 100px;
}

nav.navigation-menu {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

nav.navigation-menu>ul>li>a {
  color: #FAB301;
}
```

```html
<header class="top-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./dist/img/usjr-logo.png" alt="" href="http://www.usjr.edu.ph" id="logo">
    </div>

    <nav class="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Link A1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link A2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link A3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navigation-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link B1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely position it over the top area, and use `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%));` to center it vertically.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Open+Sans');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300');

/*@import "heading.css" ; */


/*Main Elements*/

* {
  - margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #ececec;
  font: 14px/20px'Nunito', 'sans-serif';
  color: #444;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

img#logo {
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav.top-nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav.top-nav > ul > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

header.top-header {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 100px;
}

nav.navigation-menu {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

nav.navigation-menu > ul > li > a {
  color: #FAB301;
}
  
.top-header .container {
    position: relative;
}
  
.top-nav {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="top-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="./dist/img/usjr-logo.png" alt="" href="http://www.usjr.edu.ph" id="logo">
    </div>

    <nav class="top-nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Link A1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link A2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link A3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>

<nav class="navigation-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link B1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link B4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Ok, let me try this.